# Set value from another dataframe

Tags: pandas

Having a data frame `exex` as

```
    EXEX    I   J
1   702     2   3
2   3112    2   4
3   1360    2   5
4   702     3   2
5   221     3   5
6   591     3   11
7   3112    4   2
8   394     4   5
9   3416    4   11
10  1360    5   2
11  221     5   3
12  394     5   4
13  108     5   11
14  591     11  3
15  3416    11  4
16  108     11  5
```

is there a more efficient pandas approach to update the value of an existing dataframe `df` of 0 to the value `exex.EXEX` where the `exex.I` field is the index and the `exex.J` field is the column? Is there a way in where to update the data by specifing the name instead of the row index? This is because if the name fields change, the row index would be different and could lead to an erroneous result.

i get it by:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(0, index = range(1,908), columns=range(1,908))
for index, row in exex12.iterrows():
    df.set_value(row[1],row[2],row[0])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assign to `df.values`

```
df.values[exex.I.values - 1, exex.J.values - 1] = exex.EXEX.values

print(df.iloc[:5, :5])

   1     2    3     4     5
1  0     0    0     0     0
2  0     0  702  3112  1360
3  0   702    0     0   221
4  0  3112    0     0   394
5  0  1360  221   394     0
```

Comment: Could you explain why the -1 is necessary if the index of both dataframes start at 1 and the i,j fields should correspond to the correct cell?

Comment: the `-1` because `numpy` arrays are `0-indexed`

Comment: That's good to remember since it can lead to a messy error. Thanks for the helpful answer.